# How to create array of variables in pine script

Tags: arrays, list, pine-script, tradingview-api, moving-average

I have created in tradingview (pine script) three Exponential Moving Averages and I want to create an array from such EMA's.

I have tried this:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
ema3 = ta.ema(close,3)
ema6 = ta.ema(close,6)
ema9 = ta.ema(close,9)


arr = array.new_float([ema3,ema6,ema9])
```

But I get this error:

```
Cannot call 'array.new_float' with argument 'size'='ema3,ema6,ema9'. An argument of '[series float, series float, series float]' type was used but a 'series int' is expected.
```

I need to create an array (or a list) containing those EMA's. For example, in Python I'd do:

arr = [ema3,ema6,ema9]

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `array.from()` function.

> The function takes a variable number of arguments with one of the
> types: int, float, bool, string, label, line, color, box, table,
> linefill, and returns an array of the corresponding type.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

ema3 = ta.ema(close,3)
ema6 = ta.ema(close,6)
ema9 = ta.ema(close,9)

arr = array.from(ema3, ema6, ema9)

plot(array.get(arr, 0), color=color.green)  // ema3
plot(ema3, color=color.red)                 // ema3
```